# Why Does java BigDecimal division results different than Double division when using RoundingMode

Tags: java, bigdecimal, floor, ceil

I have been working on a tolerance calculation code written in `Double`, having precisions and rounding issues I decided to move on to `BigDecimal` considering it's more precise and less likely to encounter rounding issue.
In a calculation, piece of code uses `Math.floor()` and `Math.Ceil` when dividing values.

Strange observation that `ROUNDING_MODE.floor` and `ceil` does not actually apply when using `BigDecimal`, here's the minimal re-producable example.

```java
Double doubleFloor = Math.floor(5.5/1.0);
Double doubleCeil = Math.ceil(5.5/1.0);
System.out.println(doubleFloor);
System.out.println(doubleCeil);  
    
BigDecimal bigDecimalFloor = BigDecimal.valueOf(5.5).divide(BigDecimal.ONE,1,RoundingMode.FLOOR);
BigDecimal bigDecimalCeil = BigDecimal.valueOf(5.5).divide(BigDecimal.ONE,1,RoundingMode.CEILING);
System.out.println(bigDecimalFloor);
System.out.println(bigDecimalCeil);
```

I'd expect to print identical value for such small division however I get following, floor and ceil does not seem to be calculated as expected.

```
5.0
6.0
5.5
5.5
```

What is it that I am missing. ?

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To quote the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide-java.math.BigDecimal-int-java.math.RoundingMode-)

> If rounding must be performed to generate a result with the specified scale, the specified rounding mode is applied.

`5.5` doesn't need to be rounded when the scale is 1, so the rounding mode isn't applied.

It would work like `Math.floor` and `Math.ceil` if the scale were 0:

```
BigDecimal bigDecimalFloor = BigDecimal.valueOf(5.5).divide(BigDecimal.ONE,0,RoundingMode.FLOOR);
BigDecimal bigDecimalCeil = BigDecimal.valueOf(5.5).divide(BigDecimal.ONE,0,RoundingMode.CEILING);
System.out.println(bigDecimalFloor);
System.out.println(bigDecimalCeil);
```

Output

```
5
6
```

Comment: Thanks, just figured it out :)